# Date conversion in Java and Oracle

Tags: java, oracle

I work with oracle. I have a problem in my java code. This problem is related to date.

In my *local* environment I have this kind of date

**Tue Jul 08 00:00:00 GMT+03:00 2014**

but with the same code in the *server*  I have this date

**Tue Jul 08 00:00:00 PDT 2014**

I use this code

```
 public String getDatehjri(String date_hijrio){
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        String fromHj = null;
        String s = date_hijrio;              
        try{
           Date dFrom = sdf.parse(s);    
           fromHj= licenseService.convertDateMiladiToHijri(dFrom); 
         }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
         return fromHj;
    }

  public String convertDateMiladiToHijri(Date dateMiladi)
            throws Exception {

            dateMiladi = DateUtil.convertStringToDate(DateUtil.getDateTime("dd/MM/yyyy 00:00:00", dateMiladi));



            MiladiToHijri miladiToHijri = LicenseManagerImpl.instance.getHijriDate(dateMiladi);

            long day = ((dateMiladi.getTime() - miladiToHijri.getMDate().getTime()) / ONE_DAY) + 1;

            String dateHijri = miladiToHijri.getHYear() + "-" + miladiToHijri.getMonthNo() + "-" + day;

            return dateHijri;
        }



 public MiladiToHijri getHijriDate(Date date) throws Exception {
        return this.miladiToHijriDaoImpl.getHijriDate(date);
    } 


   public  MiladiToHijri getHijriDate(Date date) throws Exception {

        String dateStr = DateUtil.getDateTime("dd/MM/yyyy 00:00:00", date);

         String query = null;

        query = "SELECT h_year, month_no, m_date FROM (SELECT *   FROM MILADI_TO_HIJRI  WHERE m_date <= TO_DATE('" + dateStr + "', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')   ORDER BY h_year desc, month_no desc ) WHERE ROWNUM <= 1";

        Integer hYear = -1;
        Integer hMonth = -1;
        Date mDate = null;

        Transaction tx = null;

        try {
            tx = getSession().beginTransaction();

            HibernateWork hibernateWork = new HibernateWork(query);
            getSession().doWork(hibernateWork);

            ResultSet rs = hibernateWork.getResultSet();

            if (rs.next()) {
                hYear = rs.getInt("h_year");
                hMonth = rs.getInt("month_no");
                mDate = rs.getDate("m_date");
            }

            tx.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            tx.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return new MiladiToHijri(hMonth, hYear, mDate);
    }
```

**Updated**

I  make same display  to find the error

```
 public String convertDateMiladiToHijri(Date dateMiladi)
            throws Exception {

            dateMiladi = DateUtil.convertStringToDate(DateUtil.getDateTime("dd/MM/yyyy 00:00:00", dateMiladi));

            MiladiToHijri miladiToHijri = LicenseManagerImpl.instance.getHijriDate(dateMiladi);


            System.out.println("  time   "+dateMiladi.getTime());
            System.out.println("  mdate   "+miladiToHijri.getMDate());



            long day = ((dateMiladi.getTime() - miladiToHijri.getMDate().getTime()) / ONE_DAY) + 1;

            String dateHijri = miladiToHijri.getHYear() + "-" + miladiToHijri.getMonthNo() + "-" + day;

            return dateHijri;
        }
```

and I have this result

```
01:55:39,143 INFO  [stdout] (http--10.1.2.154-8080-6)   time   1404802800000

01:55:39,147 INFO  [stdout] (http--10.1.2.154-8080-6)   mdate   null
```

this is my java class **MiladiToHijri**

```
import java.util.Date;

/**
 * MiladiToHijri generated by hbm2java
 */
public class MiladiToHijri implements java.io.Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Integer monthNo;
    private Integer HYear;
    private Date MDate;
public MiladiToHijri() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

    public MiladiToHijri(Integer monthNo, Integer hYear) {
        super();
        this.monthNo = monthNo;
        HYear = hYear;
    }

    public MiladiToHijri(Integer monthNo, Integer hYear, Date mDate) {
        super();
        this.monthNo = monthNo;
        HYear = hYear;
        MDate = mDate;
    }

    public Integer getMonthNo() {
        return monthNo;
    }

    public void setMonthNo(Integer monthNo) {
        this.monthNo = monthNo;
    }

    public Integer getHYear() {
        return HYear;
    }

    public void setHYear(Integer hYear) {
        HYear = hYear;
    }

    public Date getMDate() {
        return MDate;
    }

    public void setMDate(Date mDate) {
        MDate = mDate;
    }




}
```

as you see I use     **import java.util.Date;**

the problem that the return  **miladiToHijri.getMDate()**   is **null**

Comment: Where is the point you check these dates? Is it after saving to DB of before ?

Comment: Probably unrelated but: why do you convert the date to a string? Use a `PreparedStatement` and `setTimestamp()` much more robust and easier to use.

Comment: Are you using java.util.Date or java.sql.Date?

Comment: I hope this would be the mismatch between the time stamp set in server and in your local machine. And let us know where and when do you exactly check the dates?

Comment: I have upadated my question, the problem is the result of miladiToHijri.getMDate() which is null ,  I use in my date : java.util.Date;

Comment: what does this do `LicenseManagerImpl.instance.getHijriDate(dateMiladi);`

Comment: it call this method  :  public MiladiToHijri getHijriDate(Date date) throws Exception {
        return this.miladiToHijriDaoImpl.getHijriDate(date);
    }

Comment: and  miladiToHijriDaoImpl.getHijriDate(date);     call   this method  :  public  MiladiToHijri getHijriDate(Date date) throws Exception { String dateStr = DateUtil.getDateTime("dd/MM/yyyy 00:00:00", date);

         String query = null;  .....    this method is already declared in my question

Comment: I know it calls the method but what is `instance` some static member?